# Query to select value from drop down menu for given range

Tags: php, html, sql, input

I  am making metrimonial website where I want to make a search query based on criteria having different age groups in drop down menu

```
<select class="form-input" id="age" name="age"  >
    <option value="Age"> <div class="dot"></div> Age</option>
    <option value="1"> <div class="dot"></div> 0-20/option>
    <option value="2"> <div class="dot"> </div>21-30</option>
    <option value="3"> <div class="dot"></div> 31-40</option>
    <option value="4"> <div class="dot"></div> >40 </option>
</select>
```

I want to display all the users satisfying any of above age criteria
I tried using switch case for above in sql but I didnt get any result .

```
$age = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['age']);
echo $age;

switch ($age) {
    case 1: $age = ' AND age BETWEEN 100 AND 130 ';  break;
    case 2: $age = ' AND age BETWEEN 131 AND 150 ';  break;
    case 3: $age = ' AND age BETWEEN 151 AND 200 ';  break;
}

$result = mysqli_query($db,
    "SELECT * 
    FROM approved_user 
    WHERE 
        first_name= '$fn'
        OR age=$age "
) or die(mysqli_error($db));

while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $id     = $row3['id'];
    $fname  = $row3['first_name'];
    $lname  = $row3['surname'];
    $dob    = $row3['dob'];
    $gender = $row3['gender'];
    $age    = $row3['age'];
}
```

So please Help.

Comment: If you'd check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php), you'll notice you're getting a syntax error, because `WHERE (first_name = 'bob') OR ( AND age between 100 and 130)` is not valid syntax. Drop the AND

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) after your query to find out why it's failing. Since you're not using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), you can try echoing out your query and running it directly in the database to see if it works there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query that you generate does not make sense.

Given the following value for example :

```
$age = "  AND age BETWEEN 100 AND 130 ";
```

This expression :

```
"SELECT * FROM approved_user WHERE (first_name= '$fn') OR  (age=$age)"
```

Will actually generate :

```
"SELECT * FROM approved_user WHERE (first_name= '$fn') OR  (age= AND age BETWEEN 100 AND 130)"
```

This is not valid SQL. You probably want :

```
switch ($age) {
    case 1: $filter = "100 AND 130";  break; 
    case 2: $filter = "131 AND 150";  break;  
    case 3: $filter = "151 AND 200";  break;   
 }

 $result = mysqli_query($db,
    "SELECT *
    FROM approved_user 
    WHERE 
        first_name= '$fn' 
        OR age BETWEEN $filter"
) or die(mysqli_error($db));
```

Comment: Its not working when i execute above query my page keep loading